# Babel helper-module-transforms runs into undefined is not a function

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am running mocha unit tests that are written in ES6. Using Babel to run the tests and running into a very bizarre error. This happens as soon as I import something from multiple test scripts. If ES6 Import is used from only one single test script everything works fine.

Here is a snippet of what the error looks like and I have a video that shows exactly how it can be reproduced.

/node_modules/@babel/helper-module-transforms/lib/normalize-and-load-metadata.js:37:52

TypeError: undefined is not a function

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jm0p1ttwFZc

Here is the git repo of the problem.

1. npm install
2. in /server

https://github.com/jiminssy/BabelProblem

Comment: Are you maybe loading some weird polyfill that would affect arrays?

Comment: The babel polyfill here was put in because I suspected that I need it for the array operation in the error. Even without the polyfill it runs into same problem. I am not using any other polyfill. I will upload the various config file details in the post.

Comment: Would you be able to make a reduced reprodicible example? That error is very strange.

Comment: I will strip out my server code and upload this problem as a public repo on Github.

Comment: Ok I just duplicated my entire project and made a separate public repo. You should find the link in the original post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/collections. It replaces many ES6-standard libraries with its own versions that do not conform to the standard behaviors that Babel is expecting and relies on to compile files.

Your option option would be to drop that library, or drop `@babel/register`. I'd recommend dropping the library since it seems to be extremely poorly designed.

Comment: Wow thanks! I will try this out and come back with results.

Comment: Yap worked perfectly without the collections library. Thank you for taking the time to look into this. I will notify this issue to the authors of that library.